# add multiple authentication handlers to request call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

In `urllib.requests` you can build openers where you can pass multiple authentication handlers. Can you do the same thing with Python requests?

The samples on the requests doc site show only passing one auth handler at a time, but I need to pass two. Is this possible?

Can someone provide the syntax/doc on how do to this?

Here is how I would do it in urllib.requests package:

```
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
# If we knew the realm, we could use it instead of None.
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler1 = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
handler2 = urllib.request.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(password_mgr)
# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener([handler1, handler2])

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib.request.urlopen use our opener.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: What are you speaking about? HTTP Auth headers? like `Authorization: Basic footer`?

Comment: @Arount I want to pass for example both the HttpBasicAuth and HTTPDisgestAuth to the request.  In urllib.requests get/post operations allow for the openers to handle multiple handler objects, so if it encounters Basic auth, it will use the basic handler, and digest, it will use the digest handler.  The site I'm working with and sub-sites has mixed security.

Comment: Can you please paste working code using `urllib` you want to translate in `requests`?

Comment: @Arount added the urllib.requests example

Comment: @codebase5000 you were right, auth handlers could be chained, I misunderstood urllib logic. to my knowledge, `requests` authentication mechanism do not rely on http error 401 response, but before a http request is issued, event hook is not helping here too. IMO you could wrap try exception around, to test workable auth method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Requests does not support this.  I posted this question on the github Issue's page.  The suggestion was to use: http://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#guessauth

I haven't tried it yet, but it seems to be a workable solution.